# How to pass an argument from a c++ program to cmd?

Tags: c++, command-line, cmd

I am trying to use an input of a user to be used as an argument that will be passed to cmd...

I know that to use cmd from my program I need to use this:

```
system("SayStatic.exe hello world");
```

but this is what I need:

```
char item[100];
gets(item);
//after getting the input I need to pass it to SayStatic.exe that is the part I dont know
```

I know I cannot use sysytem(); for that but others like spawnl() or execl() would work?

Comment: Why can't you use `system()`?

Comment: I need the argument to be a variable

Comment: Don't _ever_ use `gets` for input by the way, it's a massive hole, easily usable for buffer overflows. In any case, C++ programmers should be using `iostream` stuff, not `cstdio` stuff.

Answer (score 3):

First, never use `gets()`. It should never have been included in the standard library, as input that is longer than the string will overwrite stack memory and cause undefined behaviour (probably a crash of some kind). `fgets()` is an acceptable substitute, if you're using C strings.

You can do this using C++ strings like this:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
system(("SayStatic.exe " + line).c_str());
```

Comment: Whether it should have been _included_ is debatable - the mandate of ANSI was to codify existing practice rather than design a new language and ISO takes backwards compatibility very seriously. What's not debatable is the fact that we should never use it :-) Regardless, +1 for solving the problem, especially without the use of `sprintf` et al.